# Join tables and return data in comma separated

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement as mentioned below. Query needs to fetch data on SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

Tried my best to fetch the data as mentioned below but couldn't. Really appreciate your help.

Product_table

```
SKU   UPC   Details  Weight  Color  
223   111   TShirt    25     White
224   114   Pants     25     Black
225   115   Abc       29     Yellow
230   116   XyX       23     Pink
226   117   AXYz      25     Red
226   118   Abdc      26     White
228   119   Abcr      20     Pink
229   120   Abcy      22     Green
```

Custom_tbl

```
SKU   Custom_name   Custom_value
223     Pickup           true
223     eligible         false
223     size             medium
223     map              red
224     pickup           false
224     eligible         false
224     map              green
225     Pickup           true
225     eligible         true
225     size             large
225     department       001
225     availability     true
226     Pickup           true
226     size             large
226     map              blue
226     availability     true
229     eligible         true
```

From the above two tables mentioned query needs to fetch data as mentioned below.

Note: CustomValues (sixth column in example table) are comma separated and I need only 3 values in order (Pickup, eligible, map columns in Custom_tbl and rest needs to be ignored. If any custom_name is not available then it should return empty string (Check from 3rd row) as shown in below)

```
SKU   UPC   DETAILS  WEIGHT   COLOR      CustomValues
223   111   TShirt    25      White      true,false,red
224   114   Pants     25      Black      false,false,green
225   115   Abc       29      Yellow     true,true,
226   118   Abdc      26      White      true,,blue
228   119   Abcr      20      Pink       ,,,
229   120   Abcy      22      Green      ,true,
```

Can any help me in modifying the query for same above data but I need to exclude data whose Custom_name is eligible and value is false. I have this query which gets what I am looking for the original question but unable to add the condition what I am looking for.   Appreciate your help on this.

For same above data I need to exclude data whose Custom_name eligible and value is false. I have this query but unable to add above logic

```
SELECT productDetails.sku, Isnull(productDetails.sku, '') + ',' 
       + Isnull(productDetails.upc, '') + ',' 
       + Isnull(productDetails.details, '') 
       + ',' + CustomValues 
        FROM  (SELECT PD.*, 
               Stuff((SELECT ',' + Attributes.customval 
                     FROM   (SELECT 
                     A.sku, 
                     Isnull(Max(A.[Pickup]), '') + ',' 
                     + Isnull(Max(A.[eligible]), '') + ',' 
                     + Isnull(Max(A.[size]), '') AS customVal
                     FROM ( SELECT sku, Isnull(CASE WHEN custom_name = 'Pickup' THEN Max(custom_value) END, '') AS 'Pickup', 
                                       Isnull(CASE WHEN custom_name = 'eligible' THEN Max(custom_value) END, '') AS 'eligible', 
                                       Isnull(CASE WHEN custom_name = 'size' THEN Max(custom_value) END, '') AS 'size'
                            FROM  [product_custom_details]
                            GROUP  BY sku, custom_field_name ) AS A                                                       
                            GROUP  BY A.sku ) Attributes 
                      WHERE  Attributes.sku = PD.sku 
                      FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS CustomValues 
        FROM   [product_details] PD) AS productDetails 
ORDER  BY productDetails.sku
```

Comment: `"I need only 3 values in order"`, what order is that?

Comment: Check stuff function, that will solve your problem here

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.SKU,P.UPC,Details,P.[Weight],P.[Color],
STUFF((SELECT ',' + Custom_value 
       from  Custom_tbl 
       where SKU=P.SKU FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS Customvalues
FROM Product_table P
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` in `Custom_tbl` table per `SKU` and use CASE WHEN to get individual custom values

```
SELECT
   SKU,
   ISNULL(CASE WHEN Custom_name = 'Pickup' THEN Custom_value END,'') + ','
   ISNULL(CASE WHEN Custom_name = 'eligible' THEN Custom_value END,'') + ','
   ISNULL(CASE WHEN Custom_name = 'map' THEN Custom_value END,'') as CustomValues
FROM Custom_tbl
WHERE Custom_name IN ('Pickup','eligible','map')
GROUP BY SKU
```

Now just join this with the primary table per `sku`

```
SELECT P.SKU, UPC, DETAILS, WEIGHT, COLOR, ISNULL(C.CustomValues,'') as CustomValues 
FROM Product_table P
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
       SKU,
       ISNULL(CASE WHEN Custom_name = 'Pickup' THEN Custom_value END,'') + ','
       ISNULL(CASE WHEN Custom_name = 'eligible' THEN Custom_value END,'') + ','
       ISNULL(CASE WHEN Custom_name = 'map' THEN Custom_value END,'') as CustomValues
    FROM Custom_tbl
    WHERE Custom_name IN ('Pickup','eligible','map')
    GROUP BY SKU
)C ON P.sku = C.sku
```

Comment: Thanks every one for your great help. I got what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Product_Table AS TABLE (SKU INT, UPC INt, Details VARCHAR(100), Weight INT, Color VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @Custom_Tbl AS TABLE (SKU INT, Custom_Name VARCHAR(100), Custom_Value VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Product_Table VALUES (223,111,'TShirt',25,'White'),(224,114,'Pants',25,'Black')
,(225,115,'Abc',29,'Yellow'),(230,116,'XyX',23,'Pink'),(226,117,'AXYz',25,'Red')
,(226,118,'Abdc',26,'White'),(228,119,'Abcr',20,'Pink'),(229,120,'Abcy',22,'Green')

INSERT INTO @Custom_Tbl VALUES (223,'Pickup','true'),(223,'eligible','false'),(223,'size','medium')
,(223,'map','red'),(224,'pickup','false'),(224,'eligible','false'),(224,'map','green')
,(225,'Pickup','true'),(225,'eligible','true'),(225,'size','large'),(225,'department','001')
,(225,'availability','true'),(226,'Pickup','true'),(226,'size','large'),(226,'map','blue')
,(226,'availability','true'),(229,'eligible','true')


;WITH cteCustomNames AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
       (VALUES ('Pickup',1),('eligible',2),('map',3)) t(Custom_name,StringOrder)
)

, cteProductRowNum AS (
    SELECT
       p.*
       ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.SKU ORDER BY Weight)
    FROM
       @Product_Table p
)

SELECT * , STUFF(
          (SELECT ',' + ISNULL(Custom_value,'')
           FROM
             cteCustomNames cn
             LEFT JOIN @Custom_Tbl c
             ON cn.Custom_name = c.Custom_Name
             AND c.SKU = p.SKU
           ORDER BY
             cn.StringOrder
            FOR XML PATH(''))

        ,1,1,'')
FROM
    cteProductRowNum p
WHERE
    p.RowNum = 1
```

So you acutally have a few tricky parts to your query.  First you are showing *commas* for every *position* even if that position doesn't exit.  That takes either a cross or a left join to pull off.  You are showing results that would be 1 row for each `SKU` but in your Products Table you are showing *multiple products* per `SKU` so you need a *ranking* function to determine what row you want.  Anyway, here is a way to accomplish it all.  Like the others I too recommend `STUFF()` with FOR `XML` for the concatenation.  Oh and you mention you want the strings in a particular order.